# Simple HTML/JavaScript calculator not working?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

HTML Code (Calculator.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Calculator_CSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>



    <input type ="text" name="number1" style="width:50px;" id="Number1">
    <select id="DropdownMenu1">
  <option>+</option>
  <option>-</option>
  <option>×</option>
  <option>÷</option> 
    </select>
    <input type ="text" name="number2" style="width:50px;" id="Number2">

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="submitButton" />

    <p>The answer is: <span id="answer"></span></p>

    <script src="Calculator_JS.js>"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript code(Calculator_JS.js):

```
var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
button.onclick = function(){

if  (document.getElementById("DropdownMenu1").value == "+"){
    var num1 = document.getElementById('Number1').value;

    var num2 = document.getElementById('Number2').value;

    var answer = num1 + num2;

    document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;

    }

}
```

For some reason when I click the calculate button it doesn't do anything. Any help will be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WaZy/) for your answer.

1. Your answer span was incorrectly named 'answer' and not 'Answer'
2. Your Drop Down did not have values assigned to the options.
3. You needed to Parse the Integer Values before assigning the span text.
4. Instead of using `document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;` you should use `document.getElementById('Answer').innerHTML = answer;`

Comment: It still did not display the answer.

Comment: changed my answer. see the fiddle.

Comment: No Problem @MohsenMaesumi, don't forget to select this as the answer to your question ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
<html>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Calc(){

                var num1a = document.getElementById("num1");
                var num2a = document.getElementById("num2");
                var ans = (num1a + num2a)
                document.write("<b>The Answer Is:</b>" + ans)

            }
        </script>


        <input type ="text" id="num1" style="width:50px;" id="Number1">

        <input type ="text" id="num2" style="width:50px;" id="Number2">

        <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="submitButton"         
onClick="Calc()">

    </body>

</html>
```

(Type 2 Numbers and it's will Type the Answer (x + y)) The Problem is It's Typing it As a String:
in The First Textbox the Number is 5 and in the second it's 5 too then when the Calculate Button is Pressed, it's will show

**The Answer is:** 55 and not 10...

So what you need to do is this:

```
ParseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
ParseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
```

and not

```
document.getElementById("num1");
document.getElementById("num2");
```

in the var num1a and num2a.
That's will Fix the Problem
:)

Comment: For some Reason it's **NOT WORKING** I don't know why, Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

i found two errors.

1. Capital **A** in `document.getElementById('Answer')`. When it should be `document.getElementById('answer')`. As the name of the id is in also small a.
2. instead of `.value = answer` it should be `.textContent = answer` or innerText/innerHtml.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/uVpxr/

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Calculator (html5 css3 js)

js

```
function calc(e){
 var a=e.target.innerText,b=this.firstChild;
 b.value=a=='='?eval(b.value):a=='C'?'':b.value+a;
}
var gui=document.createElement('div');
gui.className='clc';
gui.innerHTML='<input><div>'+('789+456-123*C0./='.split('').join('</div><div>'))+'</div>';
gui.addEventListener('click',calc,false);

window.onload=function(){
 document.body.appendChild(gui);
}
```

css3

```
body,html{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:#666;
}
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.clc{
 width:256px;
 height:320px;
 clear:both;
}
.clc>*{
 border:4px solid #666;
 border-radius:4px;
 font:normal normal bold 20px/56px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 border-radius:10px;
}
.clc>input{
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 text-align:right;
 padding:0 20px;
}
.clc>div{
 width:25%;
 height:20%;
 background-color:#5a5a5a;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}
.clc>div:nth-child(4n+1){
 background-color:#f36573;
}
.clc>div:nth-last-child(1){
 width:100%;
 background-color:#ffb343;
}
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/trjsJ/